# After startQuery, onQueryComplete not be called

Tags: android

I used Content Provider to query some information(Android). After I called the startQuery(), I can output the result of my query in Log. But after all the result finished, the function onQueryComplete() was not called. I cannot find the reason.

The code below is my startQuery and onQueryComplete implementations.

```
public void queryAsync(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder, IContinue<Cursor> callback) {
    this.startQuery(0, callback, uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
}

@Override
public void onQueryComplete(int token, Object cookie, Cursor c) {
    Log.e("debug","query complete!");
    if (cookie != null) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        IContinue<Cursor> callback = (IContinue<Cursor>) cookie;
        callback.kontinue(c);
    }
}
```

The code below is part of my query code in content provider:

```
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)){
    ...
    case SINGLE_MESSAGE:
        String selection3 = SEQNUM + "=?";
        String[] selectArgs2 = { "0" };
        Cursor cm = db.query(MESSAGE_TABLE, null, selection3, selectArgs2, null, null, null);
        Log.i("debug",Integer.toString(cm.getCount()));
        return cm;
    }
}
```

How can I fix this problem?